# Can't get rid of Connection header in HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

When I try to set **HttpWebRequest.Connection** to **null** as per [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.connection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), that line throws **ArgumentException**, with any **HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive** value. Is there any way to get rid of that header for good?

**UPDATE: code fragments presenting issue at hand**

```
HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create ( "http://google.com/" );
request1.Connection = null;

HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create ( "http://google.com/" );
request2.KeepAlive = false;
request2.Connection = null;
```

Comment: Can you post some code so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @spender Sure thing, did so.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you have referenced itself says

```
Exception                      Condition 
ArgumentException   The value of Connection is set to Keep-alive or Close.
```

So, you shouldn't specify the `connection` property if you are setting the `KeepAlive` property.

Comment: Updated my code samples to clarify what I mean. It throws an ArgumentException with no regards to KeepAlive property. Whether I set it or not, I still can't set Connection to null & get rid of it.

Comment: Can you post little more code and what exactly you are trying to do here.

Comment: More code would be excessive, as what I'm trying to do is precisely to make **HttpWebRequest** to stop sending **Connection** header. This was explicitly stated in my original question.